# Visual Studio 2013 Not allowing me to create a new project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, disabled-input

My Visual Studio 2013 had started to not let me make new projects (or see already made ones) on my computer.

I have installed it again 2 times, but alas, it did not work. All it did was take up 3 more gigs of space each time.

[image: The "ok" button is disabled]
The "ok" button in the **New Project** Window is disabled, and it has been like this for months, and i was forced to use NetBeans!!

EDIT: I cannot click on the exclamation mark on the top left. Just a blank box   when i hover over it.

## **FIX:**

I completely uninstalled it, and reinstalled it by downloading it again from Microsoft. It works Now, as i now can click "ok" and make a new project.

Comment: See the exclamation point at the top right?  Need to have a valid license to create. You're probably past a trial period or having some licensing issue.

Comment: @BradChristie Nothing pops up when i click it, just a blank box when i hover over it...

Comment: Is it the free version, Professional, or Ultimate?

Comment: @programmersdude its Ultimate.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with a workspace...have you tried with a different workspace?

Comment: @Csharper: You should be clicking the caret to the right of "Sign in", not the exclamation mark. Also, take a look at the notes you're getting via the "flags" icon (also on top-right, but in title bar). I'm leaning towards VS shutting you off due to rights because I can't see another circumstance for preventing you from creating but still letting you open.

Comment: @BradChristie I also clicked the caret. Nothing popped up, Like if it wasn't implemented yet. Also, The flags were just info about updates, nothing special. And i wouldn't know why microsoft would shut me off for rights, if they would shut me off for rights, wouldn't a popup, pop up?

Comment: @Csharper: I would assume so. How about Help->About, then click "Product License Information" at top right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Reinstalled Visual Studio 2013, from scratch. By Uninstalling it (not repairing it) and installing it again, it works now!