# I cannot create any web project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

For some reason I cannot create a new web project after having installed the latest [.NET Core SDK/CLI](https://github.com/dotnet/cli). In the *"New ASP.NET Web Application"* dialog window I selected an *"Empty"* project and checked the *"Web API"* checkbox, before clicking the *"OK"* button. No error messages are displayed, absolutely nothing happens. I tried a set of combinations of projects and checkboxes + tabbing and using space to invoke the button. None of it works. Also tried repairing VS and restarting computer.

Any ideas?

[image: Cannot click 'OK' button]

**UPDATE**

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio, also tried disabling all extensions and removing ReSharper. Still no success. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29053923/visual-studio-2013-not-allowing-me-to-create-a-new-project) that someone with the same issue had to use NetBeans (the horror), but solved it by reinstalling VS which does not seem to help in my case.

**UPDATE 2**

Using the `Process Monitor`, the only thing I can derive from VS2015 are success messages in finding the ASP.NET template.

[image: Process Monitor only displays successful messages when 'OK' is clicked]

**UPDATE 3**

Following `Jims` advice:

```
devenv /resetsettings
devenv /resetuserdata
devenv /installvstemplates
```

This now results in an error message:

[image: New error]

Comment: Try checking Create a directory for solution and see if that makes a difference

Comment: No difference, same result.

Comment: Uninstall, Re-Install Visual Studio haha, it is kinda a last resort but it works sometimes

Comment: Yep, I am on my way to do that now actually. I was hoping to spend my friday afternoon on the hottest day of the year doing something else but I guess I am gonna have to suffer through the choice of going for the Microsoft technology stack, *sigh*.

Comment: You should also check the event viewer to see if a specific error message shows up there. If it does, it might help you resolve the problem.

Comment: @JeffSiver, that was a good idea but unfortunately no errors and nothing from VS the entire day.

Comment: The other thing you can try, before reinstalling VS, is unloading some of the VS extensions. It could be one of them causing the issue. It could also be a waste of time.

Comment: Incredible, even after re-install of VS I have the same issue, also tried disabling all extensions.

Comment: starting VS as administrator?

Comment: Do you get any error ?

Comment: if eventlog is showing nothing, next step  would be checking with https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor what happens in the background when nothing happens in the UI

Comment: @MairajAhmad, no error.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander, repairing VS again, will try asap. I have tried as admin as well... :/

Comment: @Marcus Try this one: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/016cf45d-d6d2-4c48-ae62-6b96f75779bf/cannot-create-web-projects-in-visual-studio-2015?forum=ApplicationInsights mabey it helps you too.

Comment: try devenv /resetsettings
then devenv /resetUserData

Comment: then try devenv /InstallVSTemplates
this should reset all the templates, and you should be able to move on.

Comment: Have you looked in the "Programs and Features" control panel to see if the .NET Core SDK/CLI which was installed can be uninstalled outside of VS? The RC1 version broke some of the websites on my dev. machine, so I am reluctant to install .NET Core until it is in release version rather than a release candidate.

Comment: I uninstalled all RC1 features, all I have now are `Microsoft .NET Core RC2 - Runtime (x64)`, `Microsoft .NET Core RC2 - SDK Preview 1 (x64)`,
 `Microsoft .NET Core RC2 - VS 2015 Tolling Preview 1`.

Comment: @Marcus are you running vs on windows 10? and when you reinstalled vs did you get all your updates

Comment: @Marcus i know obviously you did {slaps own face} just checking though :)

Comment: @Marcus as an aside what were your steps to produce an animated gif of the problem? that is a great illustration you have provided

Comment: I use a tool called "Screen-To-Gif".

Comment: @Marcus ... and if you now uninstall those .NET Core features too and do a repair of VS, does VS start working?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, same issue.

Comment: @Marcus If you use "Run as administrator" when starting VS, does it work? Maybe it'll jog something into the correct settings. Or logging in as a different user. If you have an MSDN subscription, maybe you could use one of the "technical support incidents". Otherwise, by this stage, and although it is not your preferred option, I think you will get to a working system more quickly by making a complete backup of your system and performing a "Reset this PC" Windows reinstallation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, I´ve already tried that (as suggested by Falco Alexander). I resorted to a clean Windows installation.

Comment: WTF, no one suggested running `devenv /log`?...

Answer (score 4):

You can try and reset the visual studio templates and settings.

```
devenv /resetsettings
devenv /resetuserdata
devenv /installvstemplates
```

These will restore all the settings to their defaults, and also importantly, reset all the project templates to their defaults.

Comment: Wow! it would appear that your installation is really broken. There is some kind of azure component broken.

Comment: If you aren't using azure, perhaps try and remove azure related features from the install, and slowly add them back. At this point I would have reinstalled windows from scratch - format disk, start again - just my two cents worth...

Comment: I do need to use Azure and publish to Azure frequently though... I am leaning towards a clean install too. It´s just very disappointing, it feels like a free ticket to the 90's.

Answer (score 3):

It could be an issue with the GAC. This may be confirmed by [this potentially related SO thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856535/creating-asp-web-app-fails-in-visual-studio-2013)

Please open the `Developer Command Prompt` as administrator and try running these commands:

`gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.dll"`

`gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll"`

If you cannot find the DLLs in the paths I have given, please do a search in the various visual studio folders you have in Program Files until you find it, then update the path in the command above.

Comment: No success unfortunately :/

Comment: So to be clear, you found the DLLs and successfully registered them into the GAC, and you're still having this issue? Or were you unable to locate the DLLs?

Comment: I found them and I successfully registered them, but I still had the same issue. Yesterday I removed the partition with this installation, moving on to the fresh install.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I just wanted a bit more details here for future people who find this thread through searches. Sucks that you didn't get your solution though!

Comment: Yeah, I wanted a solution, but you know how it is - gotta move forward, can´t try and solve one issue forever where there is a workaround. Thanks for trying! :)

Answer (score 1):

I too had a similar situation where in I was unable to create any project. You can try going to **Windows Update** and install all the *optional* and *recommended* updates. See if this works.